# Making separate class for string values in flutter

Tags: android, string, flutter, class, dart

I was confused whether is it a good practice to make a separate class for all string values in my flutter app code.
It increases the code, but it looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Depends. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members

Comment: Your app needs to be multi language?

Comment: No not multilanguage..all strings are in english only.But the app looks lot cleaner and the variables become unchangable outside the class and other advantage is single string can be used as a constant in many places...but whether it is a good enough advantage to increase lines of code?

Comment: Dart has its implementation of namespaces, i.e. every your .dart file is often a separate namespace (if not using `part` directives for many files). So it's better to define your constants or your helper functions directly inside the file not using a separate class.

Comment: can you please elaborate about namespaces. With that logic, it is not a good idea to break down flutter widgets into smaller components, like normally said in flutter courses. or keeping a separate class for logic etc.

Answer (score 0):

It solves this problem by using State Management(GetX) with MVC Design pattern. In this way, I have already solved this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).